# Vimeo API response does not return files property

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch, vimeo

I am making a fetch (javascript React Native) to the Vimeo API with ?field=name,files and am getting a response like this: {"name" : "Video name"} but the files does not get returned in the response...

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET',uri,{
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+accessToken,
        })
        .then((data)=>{
                resolve(JSON.parse(data.data));
        }).catch((error)=>{
            return reject(error);
        });
```

I then print the final response.

```
JSON.stringify(response);
```

and get {"name": "video name"} and nothing else.
When I don't provide fields and I get everything, the files still does not show up.

When I run this through the Vimeo Playground it works perfectly and returns both the name and the files. Why is it not working here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just needed to update my token scope to support video_files!